# Can this use of CSS open my site to an attack?

Tags: javascript, css, security, code-injection

To allow my users to pick their colour scheme of my site, I decided to add a "Settings" page that lets them pick their colours. The simplest way to choose a colour that I could think of was to let them type a colour's name, and have the text they enter fed directly into the CSS of the elements. This code shows the idea.

```js
var saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
var saveBox = document.getElementById('textToSave');

var colourBox = document.getElementById("colourBox");

saveButton.onclick = function() {
  colourBox.style.backgroundColor = saveBox.value;
}
```

```css
#colourBox {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
input {
  margin: 0px;
}
input,
Button {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<input id="textToSave" type="text">
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>

<br>

<div id="colourBox"></div>
```

Since I'm directly feeding user input into the element though, I'm worried this might open my site up to an injection attack.

I know very little about exploits though. The best I could do to attempt an injection attack was to enter the following "colour" into the text box:

```
yellow; width: 200px;
```

But the second statement was dropped, likely because I'm specifying in the JavaScript that I'm changing the background colour, and not the style in general.

Is the above fiddle susceptible to an injection attack?

Comment: Firstly, do the users only _ever_ see their _own_ settings?  If so, the only person they can attack is themselves.

Comment: You should put the smallest amount of code to show off what you think could be susceptible to injection in the question itself; not solely in a fiddle. If JSFiddle goes down, then no one can see what you're talking about.  (That's why we have an on-hold reason that addresses questions that don't have the required code in them).

Comment: @JamesThorpe It affects anyone who can see the page; so it depends on how that's set up.

Comment: @James Thorpe I'm not worried about them changing their own view of the site, I'm worried that they could use this to run a malicious script. I don't even know if this is possible via CSS though.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sorry, you're right. It looks like someones already done the edit though. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't exactly match the question text: _"fed directly into the CSS of the elements"_ implies being written out into a `<style>` block etc vs `colourBox.style.backgroundColor = saveBox.value;` - if you're only ever setting it via this JS, then no - it's not an issue, the browser will simply throw away anything not valid for this property.

Comment: It's extremely dangerous to the user.  They might hack their own browser!!

Comment: I don't think it's a risk, but it's a pretty weak user experience. There are plenty of color picker widgets out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be safe. You're not assigning to the `style` attribute in general, you're assigning specifically to `element.style.backgroundColor`. This doesn't get re-parsed as HTML or a CSS style string.

If it's not a valid color specification, it will just be ignored.

Note that this would not be entirely safe if you were doing this with an attribute that allows URLs, such as `background-image`. The user could then enter the URL for any remote site, and execute code there. This might allow for some kinds of XSS exploits.

Comment: More of a problem with `background-image` would be unsafe URL types like `javascript:`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="color" />`

Comment: I thought this had very poor browser support? I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Note also that `Button` not appear to be valid selector at `css`

Comment: @Carcigenicate [It does indeed](http://caniuse.com/#search=color) - No support in IE, Edge or Firefox as yet.

Comment: @Carcigenicate See http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker at "Color picker examples:"

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript and CSS run on client side (browser), it can not be used to attack to your website back-end. The worst case is that a user breaks his own view, but a page/browser refresh will undo the bad view. I hope this addresses your question.